# Job Search/Matching by Organization Type: Consulting vs. Product

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

I think the job search and matching would really benefit from additional criteria about the organization/department offering jobs. An Organization/Work Type (or similar name) would allow developers to look for jobs offered by companies that are consulting vs. product oriented.

Some developers really favor working on varying projects over time as clients hire their company to develop solutions. Others would much rather work on a single product or suite of products sold/leased to customers (B2C or B2B).

There is even a third type that may not always apply to the entire organization. The job in question may be for a developer to work on internal tools for the company.

I understand there is an Industry field already, but I still feel something more generic could benefit our searches. If I'm just not interested in consulting organizations anymore, I have no real way to indicate that in my job search/match preferences.

Therefore, a new job search preference for Organization/Work Type could consist of the following 3 options that developers can select *any combination* of.

- Consulting (clients hire project-to-project)
- External Products (products are sold to customers)
- Internal Tools (tools augment the company)

I found a decent [article comparing consulting vs. product organizations](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/consulting-organizations-vs-product-shanif-dhanani). There are no doubt plenty more on the subject, with reasoning for preferring one over the other.

Comment: Agree that providing more specific information about projects is useful. We're considering this for the 2017 roadmap; marking this as deferred until we have more concrete plans.